# How to deserialize JSON objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, deserialization

I'm trying to use the get request by:

```
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/v1/users/external/1/features/DOWNLOAD7ab8d82b40/alloc?paymentPlanId=PRO_SUBSCRD725FCCCC6");
  req.add_field('ISV_API_KEY', '548f3d4b34ffdb2f294a870a9728af6940a75b66ba944d8ab6eef5a7543ca3db'); 
  req.add_field('ISV_API_SECRET', '69dafa8923f2b0da8153e6bcca3841de0fa88f1a031a5eb1946e54eb982cef48');                           

  res = Net::HTTP.start("localhost", 3000) {|http|
      res = http.request(req)
  }
```

**'postman` is an application that shows me the result of this request**

According to the `postman`, this request returns me:

```
{
"total":"1200.0",
"used":"35.0",
"available":1165.0
}
```

How can I deserialize this Json object? Assuming I want the "used" parameter.

I tried:

```
json_string = req2.to_json
puts json_string
```

but I got:

```
{"accept":["*/*"],"user-agent":["Ruby"],"isv_api_key":["548f3d4b34ffdb2f294a870a9728af6940a75b66ba944d8ab6eef5a7543ca3db"],"isv_api_secret":["69dafa8923f2b0da8153e6bcca3841de0fa88f1a031a5eb1946e54eb982cef48"]}
```

I also tried:

```
puts JSON.parse(res)
```

but I got:

```
can't convert Net::HTTPOK into String
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Ruby's JSON library.

```
res = '{"total":"1200.0","used":"35.0","available":1165.0}'
JSON.parse(res) # => {"total"=>"1200.0", "used"=>"35.0", "available"=>1165.0}
```

Note: If you're on Ruby 1.8.X you may have to require the json class. Rails requires it for you if you are working within a rails app.

Comment: I'm trying to do:

puts JSON.parse(res)

but I got an error (I'm updating my topic).

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse(res.body)`?

Comment: @mdepolli, there are a lot of errors: 757: unexpected token at '<!-- Footnotes Style -->
        <style type="text/css">
          #footnotes_debug {font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; margin: 2em 0 1em 0; text-align: center; color: #444; line-height: 16px;}
          #footnotes_debug th, #footnotes_debug td {color: #444; line-height: 18px;}
          #footnotes_debug a {color: #9b1b1b; font-weight: inherit; text-decoration: none; line-height: 18px;}
          #footnotes_debug table {text-align: center;}
          #footnotes_debug table td {padding: 0 5px;}

Comment: it was my mistake :/ I wrote 'res2' instead of 'res' (I have both parameters)